# How I make my function in a rock, pepper, scissors game wait for a button press in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

So I have this code(I added the whole JS code but the part I want help is in the function game) that simply runs 5 rounds of a game of rock, papper, scissors with a press of a button in my html file.

The thing is that each round I want the function to wait for a button click of any of the three buttons (rock, papper or scissors)

I will appriciate any help, thank you and have a nice day!

```
let rock = "Rock";
let papper = "Papper";
let scissors = "Scissors";
let wins = 0;
let playerSelection;

const btnrock = document.getElementById('btn1');
const btnpapper = document.getElementById('btn2');
const btnscissors = document.getElementById('btn3');
const btnplay = document.getElementById('game')

function getPlayerChoice() {
  
  btnrock.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
    playerSelection = rock;
    return playerSelection;

  });
  
  btnpapper.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
    playerSelection = papper;
    return playerSelection;
  
  });
  
  btnscissors.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
    playerSelection = scissors;
    return playerSelection;

  });

}


btnplay.addEventListener('click', game)



function getComputerChoice() {

  let min = Math.ceil(0);
  let max = Math.floor(2);
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); 

  if (random == 0)
  {
    return rock;
  }
  if (random == 1){
    return papper;
  }
  if (random == 2){
    return scissors;
  }
}




function playRound(playerSelection,pcChoice) {


  if(pcChoice == rock && playerSelection == papper) {
    wins++;
    return "Player Wins!";
  }

  else if (pcChoice == rock && playerSelection == scissors) {
    return "Player Loses!"
  }

  else if (pcChoice == scissors && playerSelection == rock){ wins++; return "Player Wins!"}

  else if (pcChoice == scissors && playerSelection == papper){return "Player Loses!"}

  else if (pcChoice == papper && playerSelection == rock){return "Player Loses!"}

  else if (pcChoice == papper && playerSelection == scissors){wins++; return "Player Wins!"}

  else {return "It's a Draw!"}
}


function game() {

  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    
    const pcChoice = getComputerChoice();

    playerSelection = getPlayerChoice(); // I want this to wait
    console.log("PC "+ pcChoice );
    console.log('Player '+playerSelection);
    let roundwinner = playRound(playerSelection,pcChoice);
    console.log(roundwinner);

    if(i === 2 && wins == 0){
      break;
    }

    if(i === 3 && wins <= 1) {
      break;
    }

    if(wins==3){
      break;
    }

  }

  if(wins >= 3) {
    console.log("You are the winner of this match")
  }
  else {console.log('You lost the game');}
}
```

Comment: You don't wait for things in JS. You add event listeners when the game starts, and the listener functions do what you want when the user performs that action.

Comment: So when the user clicks on a button, you call a function that plays a round of the game with that selection.

Comment: so should I just section my game function into a "choose your option" and then into a "playround" section?

Comment: There is no "choose your option" section. The event listeners on the buttons make the choices, and that should call the play round function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getPlayerChoice doesn't really get the player's choice - it adds event listeners. Run it 5 times and you get 5 listeners hooked up to the same event. I don't think you can wait for an event to fire in a loop like you're currently trying to. This would be a perfectly fine design in a console app when you want some input from the user, but in JS when working with events you have to leverage the events to execute your game's logic.

In other words, you might want to get rid of the for loop and consider moving that logic to event chain with a listener that first adds the user's input to the board and then executes the follow logic - e.g. gets the computer choice or determines whether the game is finished or not.

Comment: Ah I see, actually I read again my assignment, and it said that I had to remove the loop and play rounds individually each time I pressed a button!
Thank you very much!